# Create websocket server to send/receive complex objects using SuperWebSocket

Tags: javascript, c#, websocket

I am new to websocket server and I'm sorry if my question looks non relevant or too easy for some of you.

I am using Superwebsocket to create an websocket server in c#.
I have setup all need to get the connection between browser and websocket server as per their sample that can be found [here](https://github.com/kerryjiang/SuperWebSocket/tree/master/Samples/BasicConsole):

I have an console app as following that will serve as websocket server :

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var appServer = new WebSocketServer();
            //Setup the appServer
            if (!appServer.Setup(2012)) //Setup with listening port
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to setup!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

           appServer.NewMessageReceived += new SessionHandler<WebSocketSession, string>(appServer_NewMessageReceived);
           Console.WriteLine();

            //Try to start the appServer
            if (!appServer.Start())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to start!");
                Console.ReadKey();
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The server started successfully, press key 'q' to stop it!");

            while (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar != 'q')
            {
                Console.WriteLine();
                continue;
            }
            appServer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("The server was stopped!");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }



        static void appServer_NewMessageReceived(WebSocketSession session, string message)
        {
            //Send the received message back
            session.Send("Server: " + message);
        }
    }
```

and I have an sample html file that will serve as websocket server consumer, all java script code that servers to connect/disconnect to server is following:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var ws;

        function connectToWebsocket() {
            ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:2012/');
            // when data is comming from the server, this metod is called
            ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
               //mesage received
            };

            // when the connection is established, this method is called
            ws.onopen = function() {
               // jQuery("#connectionStatus").html("Connected!");
            };

            // when the connection is closed, this method is called
            ws.onclose = function() {
               // jQuery("#connectionStatus").html("Not Connected!");
            }
        }

        ///send message toolbarexample websocket server
        function sendMessage() {
            if (ws) {
                ws.send("Some text");
            }
        }

        function disconnectWebSocket() {
            if (ws) {
                ws.close();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Now everything is working and I have successful handshake , so I am sending and receiving string messages.

**Now i have one big misunderstanding that I would like to understand:**

Suppose I want to be able to do two commands into this websocket server, for example I would liek to have possibility to send string messages and another possibility to send an complex object so in case if string message is sent from javascript I want `appServer_NewMessageReceived` method to be fired on websocket server but in other case I want another method to be fired something like `complexObjectWasReceived(WebSocketSession session, Prsone(type of object) object)` and in same way I want to be able to send commands from websocket server to browser to to different methods not just to onMessage function.

I can't find any good examples where it's possible to do something like that, all examples are to send/receive text messages, I will be very grateful if somebody can explain how I can achieve that or to provide some good links where I can find what I need.

*//Note:I want this websocket server to work locally for each user, and it will work as a bridge between browser and one device that will be installed on user machine that will read/write magnetic cards based on commands sent from browser.*

**UPDATE:**I have uploaded an sample solution that have all above code , you can find it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0e55uejp7e752p0/TestWebSocketServer.rar?dl=0).

Thanks all for reading and hope for your help.

Comment: You probably need [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JSON as a message protocol for most of your needs, unless you're using large Binary data.

Large binary data requires conversion to Base64 when working with JSON, and this creates a large overhead and inflates the network traffic. if you're using Binary data, read the next section.

To use JSON, you either use `JSON.parse(data) // => get complex object` or `JSON.stringify(complex_object) // => get string`.

Normally, the JSON object is a Hash map (dictionary) object, allowing you to set message fields for data.

You can use as identifier in your JSON message to select the right action.

**Remember** you need to encode the object into JSON before sending it through the websocket either from the server or from the client.

i.e.

```
ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
   msg = JSON.stringify(evt.data);
   switch(msg['msg']) {
      case 'chat':
         // do something with chat data. i.e.:
         console.log("chat from " + msg['from'] +
             ": " + msg['data']);
         break
      case 'update':
         // do something with chat data. i.e.:
         console.log("update object" + msg['id'] +
             " to be: " + msg['data']);
         break
      case 'echo':
         // do something with chat data. i.e.:
         data.ack = 1
         ws.send(JSON.stringify(data) );
         break
      // ... and so on
   }
};
```

If you need to move a lot of binary data around, you can use the first character of the message to control the type of message received (or sent).

In Pseudo code (I'll make it look like javascript, but it should be replicated on the server side as well):

```
ws.onmessage = function(e) {
   var data = e.data
   if(data[0] == "{") // is JSON {
      // regular strings in this example cannot(!) use the "\{"
      // character as a first character, as this is reserved for JSON
      // identification
      data = JSON.parse(data);
   } else if (data.charCodeAt(0) == 0) { // is binary!
      // binary data in this example starts with 1 null character padding,
      // null padding is used to signify data type and should be removed.
      data = data.slice(1);
   } else // is string!
      data = data
   }
}
```

Depending on your needs and how much user input is involved, I would consider padding every message with an identifier added to the beginning of the message stream.

This is similar to the solution above, but would create strong message typing rather than inferred message typing.

Comment: thank you for your attention, this ideas was in ,mi head but I was not sure if this is the right way,are you sure that this is the right approach?

Comment: It's either this or having multiple connections. Both approaches are commonly used. Mostly developers that worry more about scaling tend to use a single connection and either use JSON for everything or for all non binary data. Some use BSON (binary JSON), but it isn't perfected yet and it's a hassle to support. Connections are expensive resources, but it really depends on what you need. Sometimes multiple connections and separation of code are a valid option. Maintenance oriented developers sometimes prefer to have multiple connections and desperation of interests vs. resource optimization.

Comment: Hmm, using multiple connections is also good  idea, but in my scenario using Json will look much better, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: That's why we're all here :)